# How to ignore repeating rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have been wanting to ignore the repeating values by using join from multiple tables but seems like I could not find any way of my own to do it

i have three mysql tables

```
**tec_noti_send**
-------------
oid    name
-------------
1     ali
2     ahmed
3     john
4     king

**tec_feedback_noti**
-------------
fid    teacherreplied
-------------
1     TRUE
2     TRUE

**tec_query_noti**
-------------
tqid   tqnoti_got_student
-------------
1     john smith
2     harry smith
3     suzane smith
```

query I used

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tec_noti_send.*,
  tec_feedback_noti.*,
  tec_query_noti.*
FROM tec_noti_send
  INNER JOIN tec_feedback_noti
  INNER JOIN tec_query_noti
```

> Result I want

```
 **join at once with no common column and auto incremented column**
        -------------------------------------------------------
        temorary
        id         name      fid  teacherreplied   tqid   tqnoti_got_student
        --------------------------------------------------------
        1          ali       1       TRUE          1         john smith  
        2          ahmed     2       TRUE          2         harry smith
        3          john                            3         suzane smith 
        4          king
```

Comment: Use OUTER JOINs instead, and don't forget about JOIN conditions - looks like you should check id fields on all the tables.

Comment: I tried outer joins it won`t give me another table rows and it will repeat the same 1st row **tec_feedback_noti**  and **tec_query_noti**. Tried also with join id fields condition check

Answer (score 1):

You should use left join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tec_noti_send.*,
  tec_feedback_noti.*,
  tec_query_noti.*
FROM tec_noti_send  
  LEFT JOIN tec_feedback_noti on tec_noti_send.oid = tec_feedback_noti.fid
  LEFT JOIN tec_query_noti  on tec_noti_send.oid = tec_query_noti.tqid
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but it shows only three rows because in **tec_noti_send** **oid** has three rows and it is equal to others table **id**. If there are more rows in another table i cannot get other table full rows.

Comment: in yoru sample tec_noti_send had  4 rows  and the query should return  4 rows  because use left join for join  tec_query_noti  based on  tec_noti_send.oid = tec_query_noti.tqid  .. seems weird  that retunrn 3 row .. besure you are using the query in anwer  and the same data sample in your question  ...

Comment: Oh that was my previous mysql data i already deleted **tec_noti_send** 1 row and added more rows in another table to re check the query.